# What is the best way to reuse styles in ionic?

Tags: css, angular, ionic4

I have added some styles in global.scss file which I would like to use in different pages. one of them is:

```
.primary-blue-color {
  --ion-background-color: #005bbb;
}
.primary-red-color {
  --ion-background-color: red;
}
```

My plan is I will extends these styles in pages.scss. I would like to know is there any better way to reuse styles in ionic. If anyone knows then please share your knowledge. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add and use colors in following ways:

1. First add the new color in **:root** in **variables.scss**, e.g:

   ```
   /** primary green gradient **/
   --ion-color-primary-green-gradient: rgba(80, 158, 47, 0.9);
   --ion-color-primary-green-gradient-rgb: rgba(80, 158, 47, 0.9);
   --ion-color-primary-green-gradient-contrast: 0, 0, 0;
   --ion-color-primary-green-gradient-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
   --ion-color-primary-green-gradient-shade: 0, 0, 0;
   --ion-color-primary-green-gradient-tint: 0, 0, 0;
   ```
2. Add then you can use it in **.scss** file, e.g:

   ```
   .view {
       --ion-background-color: var(--ion-color-primary-green-gradient);
   }
   ```

For font size or other stuffs, you can add variables in **global.scss** and then use them by importing **global.scss** file in to scss file of component/page, such as :

1. In  **global.scss** file declare any variable:

   ```
   $labelfontsize: 12px;
   ```
2. Import **global.scss** file in to scss file of component/page and then use the variable:

Depending on your project structure

```
  @import "../../../global.scss";
   //or
                
  @import ".../../global.scss";
                
  .label {
      font-size: $labelfontsize;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i use this way:

on `global.scss` i declare Sass variable, for example:

```
$primary-color: #005bbb;
```

Then you need to import the stylesheet where the variable can be found (global.scss).

in `home.scss`

```
@import "../../global.scss";
.title{
    color: $primary-color;
}
```

let me know if this was useful for you.